# Any way to identify which QTimer was called?

Tags: c++, qt

I thought about giving additional parameters to the callback but that looks way too heavily complicated (creating a own modified QTimer object, etc.)

The other thing i thought about after reading through the [QTimer docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) was saving the timerID and checking that but as there's nothing in the callback i don't have any idea what to check against :/

If someone is interested in the special usecase:
[https://github.com/Bluscream/pyTSon_plugins/blob/master/scripts/antiAFK/**init**.py#L35](https://github.com/Bluscream/pyTSon_plugins/blob/master/scripts/antiAFK/__init__.py#L35)

Comment: How about QObject::sender()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of at least two approaches you could take:

First, you could retrieve the pointer to `QTimer` by casting the sender within the slot:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject * parent = 0);
    <...>
private Q_SLOTS:
    void onTimerFired();
private:
    void doSomethingAndStartTimer();
private:
    int m_firstTimerId;
    int m_secondTimerId;
};

void MyClass::doSomethingAndStartTimer()
{
    <...>
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    m_firstTimerId = timer->timerId();
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimerFired()));
    timer->start();
    <..>
}

void MyClass::onTimerFired()
{
    QTimer * timer = qobject_cast<QTimer*>(sender());
    if (timer) {
        if (timer->timerId() == m_firstTimerId) {
            <...> // Process it somehow
        }
        else if (timer->timerId() == m_secondTimerId) {
            <...> // Process it some other way
        }
    }
}
```

Second, you could just ditch the explicit `QTimer` usage and instead use [startTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer) along with reimplementing your class' `timerEvent` method which receives `QTimerEvent` from which you can take the timer id

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyClass(QObject * parent = 0);
    <...>
private:
    virtual void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * event);
private:
    void doSomethingAndStartTimer();
private:
    int m_firstTimerId;
    int m_secondTimerId;
};

void MyClass::doSomethingAndStartTimer()
{
    <...>
    int interval = 100; // 100 msec
    m_firstTimerId = startTimer(interval);
    <...>
}

void MyClass::timerEvent(QTimerEvent * event)
{
    if (event->timerId() == m_firstTimerId) {
        <...> // process it somehow
    }
    else if (event->timerId() == m_secondTimerId) {
        <...> // process it some other way
    }
}
```

The second method is mentioned within the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) for `QTimer`:

> Alternatives to QTimer
>
> An alternative to using QTimer is to call QObject::startTimer() for your object and reimplement the QObject::timerEvent() event handler in your class (which must inherit QObject). The disadvantage is that timerEvent() does not support such high-level features as single-shot timers or signals.

Comment: That's a great answer, now i just have to figure out a way to convert this to PythonQt, thanks!